# How was a place in OSM before some month?

Tags: openstreetmap, opendata

I am in need of looking how the place was before some months or year. I have been adding places and ways in OSM since two months in a particular place. But now, I need previous view of OSM before I started digitization. Is there any way?

Comment: See answers to [How can I view OSM as it was a year ago?](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30748/how-can-i-view-osm-as-it-was-a-year-ago).

Comment: I can't find the relevant answer here

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: It doesn't give view for specific time

Comment: That's true. Such a service doesn't exist as far as I know. It would require infeasible resources such as a really large storage and lots of processing power to save and generate tiles for every possible date. However you can render tiles yourself for a specific date using old planet files (if you can find some) or a full history extract.

Comment: Thank you. I will for it